# SICP: applicative or normal order evaluation

Tags: programming-languages

I'm trying to solve Problem 1.5 from [SICP book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs).
Consider the following definitions:

```
(define (p) (p))
(define (test x y) (if (= x 0) 0 y))
(test 0 (p))
```

The question is, what would happen if `(test 0 (p))` is interpreted in **applicative** vs **normal** order.

(Applicative: evaluate all the arguments and then apply the operand. Normal: fully expand the expression and then evaluate it.)

I intuitively feel that the answer must be that one of the two gets into an infinite loop, while the other stops due to the fact that `if` is a special form, which does not evaluate the `else`-branch if the `then`-branch is already evaluated.

**Question is:** will this happen? And which one will not get into an infinite loop and why?

**My reasoning** is the following:

*Applicative:* tries to evaluate all the arguments first.

`(test 0 (p))` evaluates `0` to `0` and `(p)` to `(p)`.

Thus the next step:

`(test 0 (p))`  --> same as above, we are in an endless loop.

*Normal*: fully expands the expression

`(test 0 (p))`  --> expanded to:

`(if (= 0 0) 0 (p))`  --> expanded to:

`(if (= 0 0) 0 (p))`  --> ... (it got in an infinite loop too)

OR: does it stop at this point, because `if` is a special form? (Even though this is true, if we stop now, we did not really expand everything first, as we were supposed...)

Comment: Note that `if` need not be a special form. We know this from [Lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Logic_and_predicates) (i.e., Scheme's granddaddy).

Comment: Also, if normal evaluation encounters a primitive, then it should evaluate the expression, not expand it again (as you say it does).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand it:

```
; Normal
(test 0 (p))
(if (= 0 0) 0 (p)))
```

Normal order continues expanding because it hasn't yet reached an expression with only primitives, which recurses into an infinite loop replacing `(p)` by `(p)`.

```
; Applicative
(test 0 (p))
(if (= x 0) 0 y))
(if (= 0 0) 0 y))
```

Applicative order applies the procedure (the `if` predicate) to the arguments that are the values of its sub-expressions. Because `if` [short-circuits](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42029/where-to-learn-about-short-circuit-evaluation/42032#42032), the expression reduces to `#t` before before evaluating sub-expression `y`.